# Heroku Application Erros Django

Tags: django, heroku, application-error

I don't understand why this application error. I followed [djangogirls-extension deploy](https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/heroku/) tutorial.

here is the output of **>heroku logs --tail --app srms-demo** command

```
2019-02-09T02:31:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9822ee2e-0b33-4163-9dd1-5d9897a5b7c7/activity/builds/e01929d2-7a31-45fe-97c3-90eab053a667
2019-02-09T02:47:00.587192+00:00 heroku[run.9364]: State changed from up to complete
2019-02-09T02:50:39.686144+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=srms-demo.herokuapp.com request_id=5859852f-3ae2-47c8-9f6e-3ba05f1c5bbb fwd="43.245.123.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-02-09T03:10:39.561398+00:00 heroku[run.2791]: Process exited with status 0
2019-02-09T03:11:20.141798+00:00 heroku[run.6801]: State changed from up to complete
2019-02-09T03:15:30.610720+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

then is visited [error link](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9822ee2e-0b33-4163-9dd1-5d9897a5b7c7/activity/builds/e01929d2-7a31-45fe-97c3-90eab053a667) and found this

```
-----> Python app detected
 !     Requested runtime (python-3.7) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
 !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

#### Update

After changing runtime.txt to python-3.7.1 pushed it on Heroku master

here is the output of **heroku logs --tail --app srms-demo command**

```
2019-02-09T02:31:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9822ee2e-0b33-4163-9dd1-5d9897a5b7c7/activity/builds/e01929d2-7a31-45fe-97c3-90eab053a667
2019-02-09T02:47:00.587192+00:00 heroku[run.9364]: State changed from up to complete
2019-02-09T02:50:39.686144+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=srms-demo.herokuapp.com request_id=5859852f-3ae2-47c8-9f6e-3ba05f1c5bbb fwd="43.245.123.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-02-09T03:10:39.561398+00:00 heroku[run.2791]: Process exited with status 0
2019-02-09T03:11:20.141798+00:00 heroku[run.6801]: State changed from up to complete
2019-02-09T03:15:30.610720+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-02-09T06:28:53.311604+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=srms-demo.herokuapp.com request_id=04075507-aa74-4f7b-b303-081b50c4d876 fwd="116.58.205.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support Seems to indicate you need to declare your runtime as either python-3.6.7 or python-3.7.1   So look in the dir root and find runtime.txt and change accordingly.

Comment: Be sure to do your version control  add . And commit after changing your runtime before doing your Heroku push so the runtime change is set.

Comment: This error is due to wrong python version in your runtime. All you need to do is to change the python-3.7 to python-3.7.1

Comment: I committed after changing runtime **python-3.7.1** and push it Heroku, but still getting Application error. Updated Post with **heroku logs --tail commad log**

Comment: You may need to furnish your code, your dyno starting and crashing could be your Procfile is incorrect, or some issue in your settings.py or your wsgi.py  the log file is kinda cryptic now. Your first error was spelled out.

Comment: Just to verify, your application still runs without error locally?

Comment: @ChuckLaPress I have verified my application a couple of time, it's all right in local server **http://127.0.0.1:8000/** .